# fatal error in Gillespie alg -*tmp* error - R

Tags: r, stochastic-process

I have the following variation of the Gillespie algorithm which is used to model stochastic systems:

```
gillespie_counter_two <- function(N,n,...) {
  tt = 0
  x = N$M
  S = t(N$Post - N$Pre)
  u = nrow(S)
  v = ncol(S)
  count_matrix=matrix(0,nrow=n,ncol=ncol(N$Pre))
  tvec = vector("numeric",n)
  count= vector("numeric",v)
  xmat = matrix(ncol=u,nrow=n+1)
  xmat[1,] = x
  for (i in 1:n){
    h = N$h(x,tt,...)
    if (h==0){
      k=1
      while (k <= n){
        xmat[i+k-1,]=xmat[i,]
        count_matrix[i+k-1,]=0
        tvec[i+k-1]=tvec[i-1] + (tvec[i-2]-tvec[i-3])*(k)
        k=k+1
      }
      tvec[n]= tvec[i-1] + (tvec[i-2]-tvec[i-3])*(n)
      xmat[n,]=xmat[n-1,]
      xmat[n,]=xmat[n,]
      break
    }
    else{
      tt = tt+rexp(1,sum(h))
      j = sample(v,1,prob=h)
      x = x+S[,j]
      can= vector("numeric",ncol(N$Pre))
      can[j]=1
      count=count + can
      count_matrix[i,]=count
      tvec[i] = tt
      xmat[i+1,] = x
    }
  }
  return(list(t=tvec,x=xmat,r=count_matrix))
}
```

When I have the following input

```r
N=list()
N$M= c(x1=100,x2=1,x3=0)
N$Pre= matrix(c(1,1,0,0,1,0),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)
N$Post=matrix(c(0,2,0,0,0,1),nrow=2,byrow=TRUE)
N$h= function(x,t,th= c(th1=0.05,th2=1)) {
  with(as.list(c(x,th)),{
    return(c(th1*x1*x2,th2*x2))
  })
}
```

so I run Gillespie_counter_two(N,1000), it produce the following error

```
Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i + k - 1, , value = 0) : subscript out of bounds
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

What is going on??

Comment: For what it's worth, I got a different error when running the code: `Error in tvec[i + k - 1] <- tvec[i - 1] + (tvec[i - 2] - tvec[i - 3]) *  : 
  replacement has length zero` Seems that the code inside the while loop is a little bit buggy.

Comment: Did you evaluate `warnings()` and see what the warning are? R's error messages are on the cryptic side. I would concentrate on fixing the warnings first. They are all about `if (h==0)` with the warning that `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used` -- in other words you are trying to treat a vector of Boolean values as a single Boolean value. R is *guessing* that you mean `h[1] == 0`, but isn't confident in its guess -- hence the warning.